# Access Query and attributes

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image: 3 Tables I'm working with]

The setup is this: every location has many different accounts. Some are supplier only accounts, some are not. Each account has many bills associated with it.

I need to do one of two things:

Create a dynamic attribute in the location table that will tell me if the location is associated with an account (or many) that are supplier only. Should be a true/false attribute.

OR

Create a query that will return all the bills for all the locations that are associated with a supplier only account. I do not want a query that only returns bills from supplier only accounts.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Most people here want sample table data (and expected result) as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: What is your question? What problems did you run into in solving your problem? Please post attempted code, any errors/undesired results, and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

**Location3PS Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Locations.Number
FROM Locations INNER JOIN Accounts ON Locations.Number = Accounts.[Location Num]
WHERE (((Accounts.[Supplier Only?])=True));
```

**Final Query to Get Bills:**

```
SELECT Bills.*, Location3PS.*
FROM 
Location3PS INNER JOIN 
(
    Locations INNER JOIN 
    (
        Accounts INNER JOIN Bills 
        ON Accounts.[Account Number] = Bills.[Account Number]
    ) 
    ON Locations.Number = Accounts.[Location Num]
) 
ON Location3PS.Number = Locations.Number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this without involving the `Locations` table, e.g.:

```
select b.* from 
(bills b inner join accounts a on b.[account number] = a.[account number]) 
inner join 
(select distinct c.[location num] from accounts c where c.[supplier only?] = true) l 
on a.[location num] = l.[location num]
```

Alternatively, you can use a correlated subquery, e.g.:

```
select b.*
from bills b inner join accounts a on b.[account number] = a.[account number]
where exists 
(select 1 from accounts c where c.[location num] = a.[location num] and c.[supplier only?] = true)
```